# AWS IAM -- Using conditionals

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am new to IAM in AWS.  And, i desire to restrict the Query for various users to only table entries where primary key matches the cognito id.  To achieve this, I created the policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAccessToOnlyItemsMatchingUserID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:table/User"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

But, when i am querying the table using Postman as shown below:
[image]

I am getting the following error:

```
"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#AccessDeniedException",


"Message": "User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/Achintest/BackplaneAssumeRoleSession is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:table/User"
```

Can someone please let me know what mistake i am doing?

---

======== UPDATE ========

I tried using policy sim, and i am unable to understand why the Query without LeadingKey as shown in pic below is allowed.

[image]

and when i provide the leading key, it says denied. See below pic:

[image]

Comment: The error message is quite clear. It states that the invoking user (i.e. `arn:aws:sts::049428796662:assumed...`) does not have the privilege to invoke the process/mechanism `dynamodb:Query` on resource: `arn:aws:dynamodb...`.

Comment: Yes. But, my cognito id is same as the primary key in the table.  so, why am i getting this error despite i am providing all credentials correctly?

Comment: I can't give you a specific answer, but my guess is that this has nothing to do with the correctness of the credentials, and it does have to do with security settings at your server side (this is a wild guess since I'm not familiar with AWS).

Comment: Indeed.  But, i am not able to figure out why, as i have setup everything as mentioned on AWS docs

Comment: Sorry, but can't really help you beyond this point (i.e. event ask even stupid questions that might trigger ideas at your side). Hope you find the way out soon. Cheers.

Comment: @achin can you verify that the hardcoded version of your policy indeed allows consumption of Dynamo?

Comment: @Kristian yes, it does.  Actually, the problem is somewhere in the following lines: "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                ]
            }      This is because if i remove these lines, the policy works well.  so, it implies, that the cognito id is not matching with primary key of table, but not sure why.

Comment: are you having the same problem as I described and resolved here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961582/accessdeniedexception-using-cognito-id-in-dynamodb/

Comment: I might also suggest, that you use one of their ready made policies. It looks like you are trying to give a user full access, so maybe try the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy. I find that using the pre-made policies tend to work better.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the request that you're issuing.  Your IAM policy is using `ForAllValues` which takes every key of the request into consideration.  Your policy may return false if some key in your request does not match some condition value in the result.

Try using `ForAnyValue` and that might do the trick.

See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. (I had the same problem)
I created a table, set up a policy and could do "query" and "scan".
The table was still empty but query and scan returned reasonably 0 result lines.

Then I wanted fine grained access control and added

```
"Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
             "${aws:userid}"
        ]
    }
}
```

from this point on AWS reported `"AccessDeniedException" .... User ... is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource...`

**I continued filling the table with data anyway - et voilà - now it works.**
So the error message might make sense if one doesn't expect an empty resultset.