# AccessDeniedException using Cognito ID in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to insert to my DynamoDB table using Cognito user Id and I am getting always "*AccessDeniedException*". I followed documentation and created table and policy for it as below. What is missing here. Please see the full stack information and request ID.

Table has UserId as Hashkey and id as rangekey

***Policy:***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:1828211111:table/Table"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*Code to save data:*

```
AWS.DynamoDBhelper.Credentials.AddLogin(Helpers.Constants.KEY_LAST_USED_PROVIDER,Helpers.Settings.LoginAccessToken );
                var identityId = await AWS.DynamoDBhelper.Credentials.GetIdentityIdAsync();

                var client = new Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWS.DynamoDBhelper.Credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext context = new Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext(client);


                AWS.Table table= new AWS.Table();
                table.UserId = identityId;
                table.id = "1";
                await context.SaveAsync(table);
```

ex = {Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException:  assumed-role/ _auth_MOBILEHUB/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1

Model:

```
  [DynamoDBTable("Table")]
    public class Table 
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey]

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBRangeKey]

        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message:

> ... is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1 ...

Add the following to the Action in your policy:

```
dynamodb:DescribeTable
```

So your policy will look like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:1828211111:table/Table"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is not a table, it is an action that is part of the IAM policy. I have edited my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: yes i understood after googling with specific word after you replied. It perfectly makes sense as i try to do like "code first"  to create table with non-admin user. But what I dont understand it, after making this question here, I played around a bit and I tried also  "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ], Is this not covering DescribeTable ?

Comment: yes "dynamodb.*" should work. If that is not working something else is wrong. Mostly I debug these kind of issues by relaxing the policy until it works and then gradually adding back the deleted parts step by step. For example, as a start, you can temporarily use "*"  for Resource, and delete the Condition part from the policy.

Comment: actually that also worked now. One last thing before I close this question. Now I dont understand the part, I actually predefined 2 attributes UserId and id in my dynamoDB, if I extend this with further attributes using my code, dynamodb:DescribeTable perfectly makes sense but If i ONLY insert UserId and id, why would I need dynamodb:DescribeTable? I am extending my question with my model as well. Please see the updated question

Comment: I am not sure why describe table is needed in your case, normally you do not need it to update or query items. I am not familiar with the java api. I think it is better to ask a separate question about this.

Comment: thanks for your help. I mark that resolved and I will ask this as separate question